# Saving view values while switching between activities in android

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm working on a tabbed application in android. In the first tab I've a search engine with textviews, spinners.. and if I filled these params and switch to other tab or to the search results activity, and I return back to this tab (search engine tab) I found that all the fields are reinitialized. But I want to keep their value in order to remember what I searched for..
Is there a way to keep my data when I switch between activities ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can override onSaveInstanceState (which will be called before you transition to a new activity) and onRestoreInstanceState (which will be called before your activity is resumed) e.g. :

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // Save UI state changes to the savedInstanceState.
  // This bundle will be passed to onCreate if the process is
  // killed and restarted.
  savedInstanceState.putBoolean("MyBoolean", true);
  savedInstanceState.putDouble("myDouble", 1.9);
  savedInstanceState.putInt("MyInt", 1);
  savedInstanceState.putString("MyString", "Welcome back to Android");
  // etc.
  super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  // Restore UI state from the savedInstanceState.
  // This bundle has also been passed to onCreate.
  boolean myBoolean = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("MyBoolean");
  double myDouble = savedInstanceState.getDouble("myDouble");
  int myInt = savedInstanceState.getInt("MyInt");
  String myString = savedInstanceState.getString("MyString");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are creating intent object to initiate your tab's activity with `addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)`. Just remove this function if you have done something like this. For example , create intent object like below,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, tabActivity.class);
```

Not like this,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, tabActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

If you do so , your will get the exact state of a tab as u left it before switching to another tab.